# Regex to match optional groups

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to make a regex which will match the following formats so that I could end up with an array of the surname, first name/initial and title.

- SURNAME/A.MR
- SURNAME/A.B.MR
- SURNAME/MR
- SURNAME/.

A and B could potentially be greater than one character.

It's driving me crazy. I can match the SURNAME and the A    or the SURNAME and the MR. But just can't figure it out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

> `^([^/]+)/([^.]*)?\.?([^.]*)?\.?([^.]*)?$`